# Angular-cli build to inline styles and templates

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I saw [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/296) that angular-cli supports inlining of css and html resources while building. How do I have to configure it? I have angular-cli version `1.0.0-beta.24`.

I tried building with `ng buld` and `ng build --env=prod --target=production`.

Comment: By the `version 1.0.0-beta.24` you mean angualr2 ? I dont find any version in this here in the change log of angular2 https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.0-beta.3/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: @Aravind angular-cli version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer on the thread. We don't have to configure, to include css and html inline, it happens automatically.

Comment: Hello @István, do you know if it is possible to configure this to NOT inline the css into the HTML?

As far as I read the CLI automatically bundles in the build and no configuration is allowed, but maybe Im missing something

Comment: Hi, sorry, I don't know and did not found how to set